# SQLITE3 export multiple tables with pattern

Tags: sql, sqlite, shell

I know how to choose some rows/columns from exact table but how can i export from 2+ tables with pattern?

Tried this

```
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM 'wpts_%' ;
```

And even this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT name FROM sqlite_schema WHERE type ='table' AND name LIKE 'wpts_%') ;
```

Last command in () can give the list of tables but i dont want to loop "for" in shell. Is there a simple way to deal it?
If possible export to separate files

UPD (to Horaciusx.)
I generated this code (after "as")

```
sqlite3 "LDlog.db" <<EOF
.output sq.txt ;
create view my_view as
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_1 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_2 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_3 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_4 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_5 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_6 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_7 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_8 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_9 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_10 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_11 ;
SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM wpts_12 ;
EOF
```

It works, but rows from different files without any separator its the first problem.
How can i get overall code not by hand but automatically (substitute generation code into last code), maybe some parenthesis?

UPD2 The desirable rerult is

```
"rows time, lat, lng, acc from wpts1"
delimiter
"rows time, lat, lng, acc from wpts2"
delimiter
"rows time, lat, lng, acc from wpts3"...
```

Or better each output file for table. I make a script so it must be code that will be ready without any further human intervention

Comment: do you need all rows from different tables as one dataset? if so, do you need a column for determine table origin? I would suggest to create a view

Comment: Sorry but SQL doesn't work like that. Can you give some kind of example of what exactly you are trying to achieve, perhaps a sample of some data and tables.

Comment: No, it would be better that i can distinguish data from each table. Maybe output in one file but with some separator. The table schemas are identical, i need just 4 columns (time, lat, lng, acc) from each column in tables wpts_*. I need this data to output to csv and then operate

Comment: What do you mean by *it works*? This creates a view that returns the rows only from wpts_1: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpXQ9Rvm4YpZEAWpXnb7N/0. Is this that you want? Edit your question and post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: I thought it was data from all tables. Added info to post

Answer (score 1):

Try this to generate the code to create a view

```
select 'SELECT time, lat, lng, acc FROM ' || name ||' union all ' 
FROM sqlite_schema WHERE type ='table' AND name LIKE 'wpts_%'
```

If you need table of origin

```
select 'SELECT time, lat, lng, ACC,' || name ||' origin  FROM ' || name ||' union all ' 
FROM sqlite_schema WHERE type ='table' AND name LIKE 'wpts_%'
```

Now create the view

```
    create view my_view
    as
    --Paste resultset from previous query
    --Remove last UNION ALL
```

Then just query the view

```
   select * from my_view
```

Comment: Tried 1 and 2 code, it gets just 0\n 12 times at output.

Comment: Generated the code, but get error while trying to make view. Maybe exists any simplier way to output from tables without generating the code, so i can automate it?

Comment: did you remove the last UNION ALL? Edit the question, add the code for creating the view and add the error message. Try running the result without creating the view(remember to remove last union all and ad semicolon)